# My app keeps crashing on opening. Im using SQlite for creating a database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Here is the code to my LoginDatabase class. I cant find an error. It crashes whenever I open it. I'm a beginner in android studio. I tried viewing all sites to compare.What am I missing? The database opens as soon as the first activity is created

```
package androiddev.task_one;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Mahe on 7/9/2017.
 */

public class LoginDatabase {
    final static String TABLE_NAME = "REGISTERED";
    final static String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table" + TABLE_NAME + "(" +"ID"+ "int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" + "NAME text" + "Age int" + "EMAIL text" + "USERNAME text" + "PASSWORD text" + ")";
    DataBaseHelper dbh;
    Context context;
    public LoginDatabase(Context context1){
        this.context = context1;
        dbh = new DataBaseHelper(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public LoginDatabase open() throws SQLiteException{
        db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void insertentry(String name, String age, String email, String username, String password){
        ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
        Values.put("NAME", name);
        Values.put("AGE", age);
        Values.put("EMAIL", email);
        Values.put("USERNAME", username);
        Values.put("PASSWORD", password);
        db.insert("REGISTERED", null, Values);
    }
    public String getPassword(String Username){
        Cursor cursor = db.query("REGISTERED", null, "USERNAME", new String[]{Username}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount()<1)
        {   cursor.close();
            return "Username does not exist";
        }
        else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
            cursor.close();
            return pass;
        }
    }
}
```

Log-

> 07-10 14:08:47.404 5443-5443/androiddev.task_one E/SQLiteLog: (1) near
>   "tableREGISTERED": syntax error 07-10 14:08:47.404
>   5443-5443/androiddev.task_one D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 07-10
>   14:08:47.405 5443-5443/androiddev.task_one E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: androiddev.task_one, PID: 5443
>                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{androiddev.task_one/androiddev.task_one.MainActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "tableREGISTERED":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create tableREGISTERED(IDint
>   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTNAME textAge intEMAIL textUSERNAME
>   textPASSWORD text)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                       Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near
>   "tableREGISTERED": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create
>   tableREGISTERED(IDint PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTNAME textAge intEMAIL
>   textUSERNAME textPASSWORD text)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1675)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1606)
>                                                                          at androiddev.task_one.DataBaseHelper.onCreate(DataBaseHelper.java:20)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
>                                                                          at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>                                                                          at androiddev.task_one.LoginDatabase.open(LoginDatabase.java:25)
>                                                                          at androiddev.task_one.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: can you share the error??

Comment: It just shows that my app has stopped when I click on it.

Comment: you'll still get the error log and share your java code also where you are calling your db

Comment: In Android Studio, at the very bottom of the window, there's a tab that says 'Android Monitor'. Click it to expand. Your error  should show up here. Post the entire log message here.

Comment: Could you point out what it wrong?

Comment: Have you listed LoginActivity in Manifest. Can you show me your logcat?

Comment: Listen @KritiAnandan. We are trying to help. Thats why FIVE people have asked you for the log. I even explained how to get it! Help us help you!

Comment: 07-10 13:58:44.912 4333-4333/androiddev.task_one E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "tableREGISTERED": syntax error
07-10 13:58:44.912 4333-4333/androiddev.task_one D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-10 13:58:44.913 4333-4333/androiddev.task_one E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: and no I havent listed this one in my manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing this line :

```
    final static String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table" + TABLE_NAME + "(" +"ID"+ "int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" + "NAME text" + "Age int" + "EMAIL text" + "USERNAME text" + "PASSWORD text" + ")";
```

with this :

```
final static String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +"ID"+ " int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " NAME text," + " Age int," + " EMAIL text," + " USERNAME text," + " PASSWORD text" + ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

In the String DATABASE_CREATE use this

```
"create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +"ID"+ " int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  + " NAME text," + " Age int," + " EMAIL text," + " USERNAME text," + " PASSWORD  text" + ")";
```

Comment: Please reformatte your answer also add a valuable link to make it a better one

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
final static String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table" + TABLE_NAME
```

To:

```
final static String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write code bellow like

```
   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

   public class LoginDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


   private static final String DBNAME = "dbname.db";
   private static final int VERSION = 1;

public LoginDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("create table REGISTERED(ID integer primary key autoincrement,NAME text,Age text,EMAIL text,USERNAME text,PASSWORD text)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS REGISTERED");

    onCreate(db);
}

public long insertentry(String name, String age, String email, String username, String password) {

    long rValue = -1;
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("NAME", name);
    cv.put("Age", age);
    cv.put("EMAIL",email);
    cv.put("USERNAME",username);
    cv.put("PASSWORD",password);
    rValue = sqldb.insert("REGISTERED", null, cv);
    // /closeDB();
    return rValue;

}

public String getPassword(String Username) {
    String rValue = null;

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM REGISTERED where USERNAME='"
            +Username + "' ";
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        String pass=  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        rValue =  pass;
    }

    return rValue;

  }
  }
```